# How to handle an error in DataPower policy rule when receiving specific error code

Tags: ibm-datapower

I have a rule in a policy, and I want to handle an error message. For example if I receive error code "0x80e003aa", stop the rule and write an input "code13" (some error code).I know there is "On Error Action", but something is not working. Any ideas?

Comment: someone please?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to make sure you catch the first error in the Rule. Set your debug logging on and produce the error. In the log you will (most likely) see a number of errors and then copy the error code of the first of them.

Create a new Match rule in your Processing Policy and set it to match on Error Code. In the selection list where you can chose error codes find the code you copied and add it. If you can't find the code in the list it is not a "main" error which can be catched and you will have to add another of the error codes.
If you are unsure, just add all of the codes into your Match Action (you can have multiple).

Next make sure that your rule is an "error rule" and that no other error rule is placed before it (higher up in the rules list). DataPower only executes ONE error rule so you need to be sure they come in order.

Another solution is to add a new Error rule with a "match all" (*) Match action and in it use GatewayScript or XSLT to check the code and take the appropriate action, e.g. for GWS:

```html
// get the service metadata, i.e. the service var's
var sm = require ('service-metadata');

console.log(JSON.stringify(sm));
console.log(JSON.stringify(sm).slice(1566));
console.log(sm.errorSubcode);

if (sm.errorSubcode === '0x01d30003') {
  // This is a XSD schema validation error
  const err = sm.errorMessage.slice(sm.errorMessage.indexOf('/validate: ') + 10).trim();
  session.output.write(err);
} else {
  session.output.write(sm.errorMessage);
}
```